# upload multiple files with Spring REST URL with RestTemplate from Android device

Tags: android, spring, file-upload, resttemplate

I am working on upload multiple files from android devices to PHP server, the code works fine when upload single file with FileSystemResource, and the API of files is String type. But I'm wondering how to upload multiple files within one request, any data structure I should use? Thanks.

**Follow up:
How to post an array such as FileSystemResource[ ] as the same param "picUrl"**
when I tried to do so, i got the HttpMessageNotWritableException, here's part of the stack of the exception

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [[Lorg.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;]
>   03-29 18:07:07.657: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:314)
>   03-29 18:07:07.667: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:276)
>   03-29 18:07:07.667: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:266)
>   03-29 18:07:07.677: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:209)
>   03-29 18:07:07.677: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:91)
>   03-29 18:07:07.687: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:624)
>   03-29 18:07:07.687: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:474)
>   03-29 18:07:07.697: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
>   03-29 18:07:07.697: W/System.err(31368):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:317)

API:

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXBgJ.png)

```
public BaseTest addDynamic(String content, File picUrl){

      MultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
      try{
          StringBuilder sbContent = new StringBuilder(URLEncoder.encode(content, "UTF-8"));
          params.set("content", sbContent.toString());
      }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
          params.set("content", content);
      }
      if(picUrl != null){
          Resource file = new FileSystemResource(picUrl);
          params.set("picUrl", file);
      }

      BaseTest result =  getRestTemplate().postForObject(
              AppContext.getInstance().getString(R.string.path_api),
              params,BaseTest.class);
      return result;
}

protected RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(true, new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
}
```